# npm "onchange" plugin ERRs with EPIPE

Tags: npm

```
onchange: process completed with code 0
onchange: change to css\myfile.css
onchange: executing "npm run build:css"
onchange: unlink to css\.#myfile.css
onchange: killing process and restarting
onchange: process exited with SIGTERM
onchange: executing "npm run build:css"
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "prefix" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code EPIPE
npm ERR! errno EPIPE
npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! write EPIPE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\path\to\project\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The `css\.#myfile.css` is an Emacs lock-file, when the original file gets saved the lock-file will be deleted.

Disabling the lock-file in `.emacs/init.el` via

```
;; Disable lock files .# as this is for single-user configuration
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

Stopped the errors happening.